# Removing specific circle and marker when location changed on Google Maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

My app adding circle and marker when my location changed (onLocationChanged) and i want to remove this specific circle and marker every time when my location is changed, and then draw it again in difrent place.
How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to remove and add marker and circle to change their positions. All you need is invoking `Marker.setPosition` and `Circle.setCenter`.

Anyway both `Marker` and `Circle` also have `remove` methods.

To call one of these methods, you have to keep reference to `Marker` / `Circle` after creating it:

```
this.myLocationMarker = map.addMarker(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

call googleMap.clear(); // that will remove all markers.
then add markers again.

Comment: i need remove only one circle and last marker, i dont want adding all markers again :/